# Error installing getch module Python 3.5

Tags: python, getch

I'm having trouble as trying to pip install the getch module.

When I use the command `pip install getch` I get the following

```
C:\Users\jpyam_000>pip install getch
Collecting getch
  Using cached getch-1.0.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: getch
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for getch ... error
  Complete output from command c:\users\jpyam_000\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\JPYAM_~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-gpiafze6\\getch\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d C:\Users\JPYAM_~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpryw1aohjpip-wheel- --python-tag cp35:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_ext
  building 'getch' extension
  creating build
  creating build\temp.win32-3.5
  creating build\temp.win32-3.5\Release
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -Ic:\users\jpyam_000\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\include -Ic:\users\jpyam_000\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\winrt" /Tcgetchmodule.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.5\Release\getchmodule.obj
  getchmodule.c
  getchmodule.c(2): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'termios.h': No such file or directory
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for getch
  Running setup.py clean for getch
Failed to build getch
Installing collected packages: getch
  Running setup.py install for getch ... error
    Complete output from command c:\users\jpyam_000\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\JPYAM_~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-gpiafze6\\getch\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\JPYAM_~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-1ybqkxk4-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    building 'getch' extension
    creating build
    creating build\temp.win32-3.5
    creating build\temp.win32-3.5\Release
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -Ic:\users\jpyam_000\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\include -Ic:\users\jpyam_000\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\winrt" /Tcgetchmodule.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.5\Release\getchmodule.obj
    getchmodule.c
    getchmodule.c(2): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'termios.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\users\jpyam_000\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\JPYAM_~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-gpiafze6\\getch\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\JPYAM_~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-1ybqkxk4-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\JPYAM_~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-gpiafze6\getch\

C:\Users\jpyam_000>
```

Please, I need some help on this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getch` module is not compatible with Windows.

Read the note on [the module's pypi page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/getch) for a Windows-compatible alternative:

> Hint: On Windows, you can use:
>
> ```
> import msvcrt
> # ...
> char = msvcrt.getch()
> # or, to display it on the screen
> char = msvcrt.getche()
> ```
>
> as a standard library alternative to this module